# How to activate WIFI service on Enterprise Linux Version 5 provided from Oracle?

Tags: linux, wireless-networking, firefox, unix

I have installed Enterprise Linux Version 5 provided from Oracle. I am able to access Internet using network cable.

Please tell me how can I enable wifi service, so that I can use internet without the network cable.

Comment: This is a SuperUser.com question

Comment: Which wireless card are you using?

Answer (score 0):

You need to use a extra peice of hardware like a wireless network adapter or a wireless router . The router would connect to Internet and then create a wirless network for you.